# Circuit-sat reduction to 3-SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, np

I'm trying to reduce this example from Circuit-sat to 3-Sat, but I got stuck. Can some one give a brief explanation step by step?

Tree: schema

[image: schema]

My attempt:

[image: attempt]

Comment: It sounds like you read an explanation but didn't understand it, and are now asking us to give a new explanation.  Well, I'm worried you might not understand that either.  Instead, please tell us what explanation you read and what specifically you are unsure about.  What's the first point in the explanation that you did not understand?  You might want to tell us what explanation you are reading, quote for context the part you didn't understand, explain what you do understand and what you don't, etc.  Help us help you by identifying what is the conceptual question your'e stuck on.

Comment: We discourage "please solve my exercise for me" as that's unlikely to really help you; and we discourage "please check my work" as that's unlikely to be of use to others in the future.  Instead, it's better to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.